# javax.xml.transform.Transformer not writing data to the file in Linux

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write data to the file and downloading it. I have implemented the below logic.

```
    public void exportData(List<Employee> employeeList,OutputStream out) {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        // create root element
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("EmployeeDump");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        Element employees = doc.createElement("Employees");
        rootElement.appendChild(employees);


        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            employees.appendChild(prepareEmployeeNode(doc, employee));
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {

    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {

    }
}
```

prepareEmployeeCode() adding the nodes to the element and it is working properly.

Above code working fine in Windows but failing in Linux. It is downloading an empty file after deploying the application in Linux. No Exception is logging.
What causing the issue. Do I am missing anything? Can anyone please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: How are you defining your OutputStream?

Comment: @JustinKSU I am taking it from the URL.

Comment: You need to check your `OutputStream`. If it points toward a `C:\something` file, it will be created as a `C:something` file in your current directory.

Comment: You wrote there are no errors, but I see 2 empty catch there. Is this real code, or you just omitted that part?

Comment: @MarioSantini - I just ommited it. In original it has logs in it.